# Cracking the Coding Interview Circular Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

The question:
Given a circular linked list, implement an algorithm which returns the node at the beginning of the loop.

Definition: Circular linked list: A (corrupt) linked list in which a node's next pointer points to an earlier node, so as to make a loop in the linked list.

Example:
Input: A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> C[the same C as earlier]
Output: C

My solution is to keep track of which nodes are seen inside an ArrayList and then once I get to a node that I have already seen, then I know that is the node at the beginning of the loop.

findBeginningLoop function:

```
public Node findBeginningLoop(Node n) {
    ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    Node pointer = n;
    while (true) {
        Node checkingNode = pointer;
        if (!nodes.contains(checkingNode)) {
            nodes.add(checkingNode);
        } else {
            return checkingNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Node class:

```
public class Node {
    Node next = null;
    int val;

    public Node(int d) {
        val = d;
    }

    public void appendToTail(int d) {
        Node end = new Node(d);
        Node n = this;
        while (n.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = end;
    }   
}
```

Her solution is to use a fast pointer and slow pointer. Is that solution much better?

Comment: What parts of the code were given to you ? e.g was `public class Node` given ? what else is given?

Comment: I don't get it - if it's a loop then there is no start. Just pick any node and that'll do...

Comment: I am guessing they meant reapting Node e.g C in his case

Comment: Your space complexity is `O(n)` which is far worse than that in the book. You will most likely be asked to implement the solution without using any additional data structures (in-place) anyway, so you must prefer the solution in the book to yours.

Comment: The correct answer is "fix the list implementation so it doesn't get corrupt." :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of space complexity, yes her solution is obviously better. Your solution requires you to maintain all nodes that have already been seen, which is `O(n)`, `n` being the size of the list.

Comment: +1. I think you would also need to factor in the time taken for the search within the `ArrayList` which, in worst case, is `O(n)` itself.

Comment: Plussed. Good point. We often focus only on the space complexity for questions like this. We shouldn't.